# Can Lagrange multipliers be used to give a good bound on the number of critical points?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, lagrange-multiplier

I will explain my problem by illustrating a simple case.

Easy question: Let $f(x,y)$ be a "generic" polynomial in two variables, of total degree $\le D$. What's a good upper bound for how many critical points (minimum/maximum) it has in $\mathbb R^2$?

Solution: The critical points satisfy $\nabla f = 0$, so we can try to count the combined zeroes of the two polynomials $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$, both of degree $\le D$. We assume they're both irreducible ($f$ is "generic"), and Bezout's theorem says there are at most $D^2$ solutions.

Harder question: What's a good upper bound for how many critical points $f$ has on a given straight line $Ax + By = C$? (i.e. minimum/maximum subject to the constraint $Ax + By = C$.)

**Approach #1: Lagrange multipliers.**

Each critical point satisfies $\nabla f = (\lambda A, \lambda B)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. So we have a system of 3 equations $$\cases{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=\lambda A \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\lambda B \\ Ax+By=C}$$
in 3 variables $x,y,\lambda$. The first two equations are polynomial of degree at most $D$ and the last one is of degree $1$. By Bezout, there are at most $D^2$ solutions.

**Approach #2: Parameterize the line.**

Suppose the line is given by $y=Px+Q$. Define a function $g(t)=f(t,Pt+Q)$. This is a "generic" polynomial in one variable of degree $\le D$. By "Bezout" (or just elementary algebra) there are at most $D$ solutions to $g'(t)=0$.

**My question:** Clearly Approach #2 gave a better result. However, I want to apply this in a harder scenario where there are more variables, more constraints, and some of the constraints are non-linear. In this scenario it seems "ugly" to parameterize the constraints like I did in approach #2, and very nice and clean to use Lagrange multipliers. But I want a better result. **How do I modify the Lagrange multiplier approach to get the better bound, while avoiding parameterizing the curve (line)?**

Comment: I don't quite understand how you count the number of solutions via Lagrangian multipliers. If you exclude $\lambda$ you get $B\partial f/\partial x=A\partial f/\partial y$, which is of lower degree.

Comment: Hmm... that's a good point, eliminating the Lagrange multiplier from the system of equations gives the right bound. I hadn't noticed that! But maybe in my scenario it is more difficult. (There are several Lagrange multipliers to be eliminated.) I will try it and see, thanks.

Comment: I would be interested to hear how this turned out.  @YoniRozenshein, perhaps you could give an update.

Comment: @Titus With the help of my advisor, I ended up noticing that for my purposes, I can take the linear constraint to be a line parallel to the standard axes, i.e. of the form $x = c$, $y = c$, etc. This makes everything easier: The restricted gradient is simply the original gradient with the constant coordinate removed.